# Permission control for custom environments in DialogFlow agent

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have an agent in DialogFlow and maintaining three environments for this agent (dev, int and prod). We have few developers who has access to this agent with Developer permissions. They can do changes in the agent and publish it to these environments. However we want to restrict them not to publish the changes to the prod.

Is there anyway we can control this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is unfortunately not.

Dialogflow Environments are actually better thought as of "previous saved versions of the agent" rather than "environments" in the traditional sense (I absolutely *detest* Google's choice of name for this reason). There is no out-the-box way to restrict a specific user the ability to push to a specific environment (you can't achieve this with Service Accounts either, as the permissions aren't granular enough).

For this reason, if you wish to have "true" environment-specific permissions, then you should set up one agent per environment (ie `dev`, `int`, and `prod`). You can then restrict who can modify the `prod` agent using the standard GCP IAM systems.